# SWT: how to get selected value in Combo which embeded in Table

Tags: java, swt

i create a column of comboBoxes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    new TableItem(table_1, SWT.NONE);
}

TableItem[] itemsCombo = table_1.getItems();            
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    TableEditor editor_1 = new TableEditor(table_1);
    final CCombo comboXX = new CCombo(table_1, SWT.NONE);
    comboXX.setItems(allValues);
    editor_1.grabHorizontal = true;
    comboXX.select(getIndexInLOV(choosenItemList.get(i), allValues));
    editor_1.setEditor (comboXX, itemsCombo[i], 0);
}
```

Then on clicking "Ok" i want to go through all comboBoxes and collect all values what they store. Still haven't found how it possible to fo.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled across this looking for something else. The way I've done this is with getChildren():

```
for(Control control : yourComposite.getChildren()) {
    if(control instanceof Combo){
        ((Combo) control).getText());
    }
}
```