# The method getSelectedItem() is undefined for the type Combo

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I'm a complete beginner in Java Basic, and having an issue with getSelectedItem().
The same question is posted before but it cannot help to solve my issue as Eclipse always returns :

> The method getSelectedItem() is undefined for the type Combo

My full code:

```
public class FormObjects {

protected Shell shell;
private Text txtComboBoxItem;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FormObjects window = new FormObjects();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");

    Combo comboOne = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE);
    comboOne.setItems(new String[] {"C Sharp", "Java", "PHP", "Visual Basic", ".NET"});
    comboOne.setBounds(30, 50, 91, 23);

    Button btnComboBox = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnComboBox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String itemText = (String)comboOne.getSelectedItem();
            txtComboBoxItem.setText(itemText);
        }
    });
    btnComboBox.setBounds(147, 48, 130, 25);
    btnComboBox.setText("Get Drop Down Item");

    txtComboBoxItem = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    txtComboBoxItem.setBounds(304, 50, 101, 21);

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "type Combo"?

Comment: That would be because, as near as I can tell, `Combo` doesn't have a `getSelectedItem` method (see the [JavaDocs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html))

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm guessing `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo` based on the use of `Shell`...

Comment: Ah, it's an SWT class and you're trying to call Swing methods. That won't work very well.

Comment: FYI- Not sure you know or not, but you're using the SWT UI framework, don't confuse it with any of the other frameworks

Comment: I drop a combox box to SWT Application and that code is generated automatically

Comment: [This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/GettingselecteditemindexfromCombo.htm) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522314/swt-how-to-get-selected-value-in-combo-which-embeded-in-table) might help

Comment: I realize it now, the tutorial I'm studying is using NetBeans and I'm using  Eclipse. Could you please advise the way to get combox value in SWT class

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer, I can get combo value now with your helpful link, thanks a lot. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use setText() to resolve my issue. Thanks all!